# Error while Download action repository 'r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1' in github action workflow

Tags: android, continuous-integration, github-actions

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnxhk.png)

Error: Could not find file '/home/runner/work/_actions/_temp_5b032fb8-b584-4bbb-acfb-d0d02db41d70/_staging/r0adkll-sign-android-release-6079bfc/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/.bin/node-which'

Comment: Not a fix to your question, but I had very similar error message in my own action and was not able to find answer to it. In my case, on modules upgrade a symbolic link was replaced by a regular file, but the symbolic link flag in git was not removed, so the action was trying to find a file with path matching the content of the file. The fix was to remove symbolic link flag in the git repository.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed by the action creator. https://github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release/issues/30